# Validar TextBox solo números, signo decimal y permitir copiar y pegar, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keypressevent

He visto aquí en SO varias preguntas relacionadas pero ninguna resuelve mi problema.

Estoy intentando que un `TextBox` solo acepte **números, un punto decimal y que ademas me permita copiar o pegar un valor en el `TextBox`** ¿Cómo crear una sola función para esto?

> Problema:
>
> - Si utilizo el Evento `KeyPress` no se como capturar las teclas `Ctrl + C` o `Ctrl + V`. No me esta funcionando la validación de aceptar solo un punto decimal.
> - Si utilizo el Evento `KeyDowm` capturo las teclas `Ctrl + C` o `Ctrl + V` pero no se como hacer para aceptar un solo punto decimal, de modo que si ya esta digitado un punto (.) no permita colocar más puntos.

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
/// <summary> Teclas permitidas en el TextBox
///(char)46 pulsan .
///(char)8 pulsan Borrar
///(char)13 pulsan enter
///(char)37 pulsan Izquierda
///(char)38 pulsan Arriba
///(char)39 pulsan Derecha
///(char)40 pulsan Abajo
///(char)48 - 57  pulsan Los números del 0 al 9
/// </summary>
public List<int> valores_permitidos = new List<int>() { 8, 13, 37, 38, 39, 40, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 46 };
```

Para Validar en el **KeyPress**:

```
public void solo_numeros(ref TextBox textbox, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
        char signo_decimal = (char)46; //Si pulsan el punto .

        if (char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) | valores_permitidos.Contains(e.KeyChar) |
            e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Escape | e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            e.Handled = false; // No hacemos nada y dejamos que el sistema controle la pulsación de tecla
            return;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == signo_decimal) 
        {
            //Si no hay caracteres, o si ya hay un punto, no dejaremos poner el punto(.)
            if (textbox.Text.Length == 0 | textbox.Text.LastIndexOf(signo_decimal) >= 0)
            {
                e.Handled = true; // Interceptamos la pulsación para que no permitirla.
            }
            else //Si hay caracteres continuamos las comprobaciones
            {
                //Cambiamos la pulsación al separador decimal definido por el sistema 
                e.KeyChar = Convert.ToChar(System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencyDecimalSeparator);
                e.Handled = false; // No hacemos nada y dejamos que el sistema controle la pulsación de tecla
            }
            return;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == (char)13) // Si es un enter
        {
            e.Handled = true; //Interceptamos la pulsación para que no la permita.
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}"); //Pulsamos la tecla Tabulador por código
        }
        else //Para el resto de las teclas
        {
            e.Handled = true; // Interceptamos la pulsación para que no tenga lugar
        }
    }
```

O Usando el **KeyDown**:

```
public void solo_numeros_KeyDown(ref TextBox textbox, KeyEventArgs e)
{
        if (valores_permitidos.Contains(e.KeyValue) || ( e.KeyCode == Keys.C && e.Control ) ||
        ( e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Control ) || ( e.KeyCode == Keys.X && e.Control ))
            e.SuppressKeyPress = false;
        else
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

> Para utilizar la función de esta forma: (Solo una a la vez)

```
 private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textbox = (TextBox)sender; // Convierto el sender a TextBox
        solo_numeros(ref textbox, e); // Llamamos a nuestro método
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textbox = (TextBox)sender; 
        solo_numeros_KeyDown(ref textbox, e);
    }
```

**Nota:** No uso las funciones al mismo tiempo, solo una a la vez.

Entorno: Visual Studio 2010, C# & .NET Netframework 4

Comment: ¿Por qué mientras escribe? Eso va en contra de todas las recomendaciones/UX. Para eso está [`Control.Validating`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating(v=vs.110).aspx) cuando pierde el foco

Comment: @Mariano comprendo pero ¿Cómo podría lograr mi este mismo objetivo en el Evento `Validating` ? Solo aceptar números y un punto decimal. Puede proporcionarme un ejemplo?

Comment: @Mariano, tienes algún link que soporte esa aseveración? sino, todas las librerías de webs SPAs están mal porque permiten validar mientras escribes. Lo que tu comentas es validación pasiva. De hecho es la primera vez que escucho que validar la entrada por medio de un formato preestablecido, va en contra de las recomendaciones para diseño de interfaces, hasta hay un control en winforms donde indicas cada posición que caracter acepte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Un problema añadido es que, aunque consiguieras hacer lo que pretendes, seguirías pudiendo tener valores no válidos de otras formas (por ejemplo pegando texto mediante el menú contextual del control).

Yo te propondría:

- Controlar los caracteres no válidos en el evento `KeyPress`
- Almacenar el valor actual del control en una variable privada
- En el evento `TextChanged` validar que el contenido del control es válido y, si no es así, recuperar el valor anterior a partir de la variable privada. De esta forma si el usuario pega un contenido no válido automáticamente se recuperaría el valor anterior.

El código podría quedar así:

```
private const char SignoDecimal = '.'; // Carácter separador decimal
private string _prevTextBoxValue; // Variable que almacena el valor anterior del Textbox

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
    // Comprueba si el valor del TextBox se ajusta a un valor válido
    if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox.Text, @"^(?:\d+\.?\d*)?$"))
    {
        // Si es válido se almacena el valor actual en la variable privada
        _prevTextBoxValue = textBox.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        // Si no es válido se recupera el valor de la variable privada con el valor anterior
        // Calcula el nº de caracteres después del cursor para dejar el cursor en la misma posición
        var charsAfterCursor = textBox.TextLength - textBox.SelectionStart - textBox.SelectionLength;
        // Recupera el valor anterior
        textBox.Text = _prevTextBoxValue;
        // Posiciona el cursor en la misma posición
        textBox.SelectionStart = Math.Max(0, textBox.TextLength - charsAfterCursor);
    }
}

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
    // Si el carácter pulsado no es un carácter válido se anula
    e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) // No es dígito
                && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) // No es carácter de control (backspace)
                && (e.KeyChar != SignoDecimal // No es signo decimal o es la 1ª posición o ya hay un signo decimal
                    || textBox.SelectionStart == 0 
                    || textBox.Text.Contains(SignoDecimal));
}
```

Comment: Igual estoy equivocado pero creo que textchanged no siempre detecta cuando se pega texto.

Comment: Sí, claro que se genera el evento.

Comment: Prueba haciendo clic derecho y pegar.

Comment: ¿No te salta el evento? Deberías revisar tu código

Comment: No se en Winforms pero en WPF no salta el evento en todos los casos.

Comment: Ah. Entonces ahí está tu error. Se trata de WinForms. Tenía que haberlo especificado en la pregunta. De hecho el TextBox de WPF no tiene evento KeyPress.

Comment: En `WindowsForms`  si se desencadena el evento `TextChanged` al pegar un dato, funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 1):

**Te muestro mi manera, no se si sea la mejor, pero talvez te sirva:
creas una variable global:**

```
  Boolean permitir = true;//variable global para saber si se permite ctrl + C y ctrl + V
```

**En el KeyPress mandas a llamar a la funcion solonumeros:**

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled= solonumeros(Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar)); //llamada a la funcion que evalua que tecla es aceptada

    }
```

**Esta es la funcion que te permite teclear solo numeros y un solo punto:**

```
public bool solonumeros(int code)
    {            
        bool resultado;

        if (code == 46 && textBox1.Text.Contains("."))//se evalua si es punto y si es punto se rebiza si ya existe en el textbox
        {                
            resultado = true;
        }
       else if ((((code >= 48) && (code <= 57)) || (code == 8) || code == 46)) //se evaluan las teclas validas
        {                
            resultado = false;
        }
        else if (!permitir)
        {
            resultado = permitir;
        }
        else
        {
            resultado = true;
        }

        return resultado;

    }
```

**Y por ultimo utilizas el evento KeyDown para permitir** *ctrl + C*  **Y** *ctrl + v*

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        bool paste = (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyData) == (Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Control) | Convert.ToInt32(Keys.V)));
        bool copy = (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyData) == (Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Control) | Convert.ToInt32(Keys.C)));
        if (paste || copy)
        {
            permitir = false;
        }
        else
        {
            permitir = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Gracias, aunque prefiero usar otro método.

Answer (score 1):

Para capturar el evento de copiar/pegar tienes que sobrecargar el método WndProc, tendrás que hacer un control nuevo que herede de Textbox y sobrecargar dicho método:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg != WM_PASTE)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
        else
        {
            // aquí controlas lo que pegan:
            double value;
            if (double.TryParse(Clipboard.GetText(), out value))
            {
                Text = value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

WM_PASTE es 0x0302

Otra solución, si estas usando winforms, es usar el control MaskedTextBox.